# Product compare session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am working on a project which require ability to compare 2 or more products. And the client required an ability for a page which links **directly** to such comparison.

The way I opted to implement it was with URL lik this: `/compare?id=5-20-100` (for comparing products wit IDs 5, 20 and 100).

Basically the whole thing gets parsed by this script:

```
$list = explode( '-', $_GET['id'] );

$myarray = $list;

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'products',
   'post__in'      => $myarray
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For adding products to the list I intend to use a session, where items are added in via AJAX (I'm using jQuery, is that matters). So, the problem I got is this:

When user clicks on "compare this product", I need get this product's ID (probably from html data attribute `product-id="100"`).

How to set up this AJAX session? More precisely: how, when user's click *"compare Items"* button, do I make them go to `/compare?id=5-20-100` URL?

Front-end update:

```
<a href="#" data-id="5">Product 1 add to compare</a>
<a href="#" data-id="20">Product 2 add to compare</a>
```

View compare products, in this part i need get url from ajax session.

```
<a href="compare?id=5-20">View compare products</a>
```

Comment: Yes, part of wordpress. I worked on a custom loop. On loop page i put out all information for products and then make a table view of sorting data.

Comment: Is it in the frontend or the backend? could you add some of the code you made so far.

Comment: This is backend part, and on backend is no problem, problem is set a ids filtering for compare page for get data.

Comment: So just to make sure i get this right. The part you want help with is making the compare?id=x  link from what the user clicks to compare?

Comment: Yes, check for question, front-end update. For example products lists, with 50 products, on each product has a button, add to compare, and the final button, link, view compare products.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use checkbox inputs with array access notation.

```
<form id="compare" method="get" action="/path/to/compare.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="checkbox" name="compare[]" value="[ID POPULATED VIA PHP]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="compare[]" value="[ID POPULATED VIA PHP]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="compare[]" value="[ID POPULATED VIA PHP]" />
...
<input type="submit" value="Compare Selected Items" />
</form>
```

This would call to a URL such as:

```
http://yoursite.com/path/to/compare.php?compare[]=ID1&compare[]=ID2&compare[]=ID3
```

You can easily access all comparison id's that are selected within `$_GET['compare']` array.  You also have bookmarkable URL since you used GET.

This also works without any need for javascript (though of course one could still add javascript form validation - perhaps to make sure at least two checkboxes are selected before compare can be used.)

Comment: But if view compare products is on other page, not in the same page, where is not locate a products? For example: products.php - products listing with buttons, compare. Other page is ex. catalog.php, or main overall header, where we need put a "view compare products". Your solution is good for single page view. Maybe use cookies? Store  , create, update, delete cookies?

Comment: @Foxsk8 It doesn't matter whether the the GET endpoint is single page or another page.  All the values for checkboxes that are checked would be passed in `$_GET['compare']`.  In this case you would simply have the product id's set as the `value` property in the checkboxes.  When you get to your comparison page, all the checked product id values would be available in `$_GET['compare']`.

Comment: Probelm solved. I need to use cookies, for latter get compare url on global button "compare products" where all posted get ids is stored on cookies for later use on all site. Problem was on front end part to set global leter use url. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for gathering the id and appending to the link will not require use of AJAX.

The solution you want  need to set a eventhandler on the links. It would be ideal to use Javascript without JQuery but as you are already using it and talking about the data-attributes you could set eventhandlers on the links, then get id using the JQuery `data()` method and then finally append it to the href attribute on the final link. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

**A better solution would be using a form**. @Mike Brant as just submitted such a solution which i would recommend to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a final code, that works for bookmarks, compare or add to cart basic function:

JS:

```
cookie_data_load = $.cookie('compare_data');
    $('.view_compare').attr("href", "http://localhost/auto/cart/?id=" + cookie_data_load);


    var fieldArray = [];
    $( ".aaddtocart" ).click(function(){
        fieldArray.push($(this).data("compare"));
        var unique=fieldArray.filter(function(itm,i,a){
            return i==fieldArray.indexOf(itm);
        });

        var str = unique.join('-');
        $.cookie('compare_data', str, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        cookie_data = $.cookie('compare_data');
        console.log(str);
        console.log(unique);
        alert(unique);
        $('.view_compare').attr("href", "http://localhost/auto/cart/?id=" + cookie_data);
        return false;
    });
```

Wordpress template:

```
<?php

$list = explode( '-', $_GET['id'] );

$myarray = $list;

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'products',
   'post__in'      => $myarray
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <!-- pagination here -->

  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- end of the loop -->
```

HTML buttons:

```
<a href="http://localhost/auto/cart/?id=24-40" class="view_compare">Show compare products</a>
<a href="#" class="aaddtocart" data-compare="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Add to compare list</a>
```