# Set cookies using js-cookies to array

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

newbie here regarding Javascript. I am following this thread to set cookies to array by clicking button. [Product compare session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712242/product-compare-session). Its working but the problem is, when i reload or open new page, when i click the button on new page or refreshed page, the cookies doesn't add new value, it replace all cookies which has been set from previous page. Here is the script.

`

```
 cookie_data_load = Cookies.get('compare_data');
    $('.view__compare').attr("href", "https://shop.local/compare/?id=" + cookie_data_load);


    var fieldArray = [];
    $( ".product__actions-item--compare" ).click(function(){
        fieldArray.push($(this).data("compare"));
        var unique=fieldArray.filter(function(itm,i){
            return i==fieldArray.indexOf(itm);
        });

        var str = unique.join('-');
        Cookies.set('compare_data', str, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        cookie_data = Cookies.get('compare_data');
        console.log(str);
        console.log(unique);
        alert(unique);
        $('.view__compare').attr("href", "https://shop.local/compare/?id=" + cookie_data);
        return false;
    });
```

`

And second question is how to limit the number of cookies value (array) from above code? Many thanks

I have read the js-cookies github but cant understand single thing.

*** Updated code from https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422082/uladzimir

`

```
 var fieldArray = (Cookies.get('compare_data') || '').split('-');     
   $(".product__actions-item--compare").click(function () {    if
   (fieldArray.length >= 3) {
        alert("unfortunately limit exceeded :(");    } else {
        fieldArray.push($(this).data("compare"));
        var unique = fieldArray.filter(function (itm, i) {
          return i == fieldArray.indexOf(itm);
        });
        var str = unique.join('-');
        Cookies.set("compare_data", str, { expires: 7, path: "/" });
        cookie_data = Cookies.get("compare_data");
        console.log(str);
        console.log(unique);
        alert(unique);
        $(".view__compare").attr(
          "href",
          "https://shop.local/compare/?id=" + cookie_data
        );
        return false;    }   });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan, whenever you reload a page, the array of data "fieldArray" is ALWAYS empty (despite there is data in "compare_data" cookie from previous browser session)

What you have to do is to initialize "fieldArray" with it's initial value taken from cookie:

```
var fieldArray = (Cookies.get('compare_data') || '').split('-')
```

Cookie stores string data with maximum size of 4kb. More over, cookie have no idea, if it stores serialized array, object, or anything else... It just keeps a string of text and that's it. So (as far as I know), there is no way to limit array length using cookie settings.

So, the only workaround here is to do this length-check programmatically, like following:

```
$('.product__actions-item--compare').click(function () {
    if (fieldArray.length >= 3) {
        alert('unfortunately limit exceeded :(');
    } else {
        // do your actions
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey its working now. Many thanks. First proble is solved thank you. For second problem, Yes thats what like you said, how to limit amount of values stored in array in cookie? Eg: If the limit of item is 3, i wanna show browser alert when the button is clicked by the fourth times.

Comment: @IvanNugraha updated and answer, please have a look

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Its working, but there is small issue. The cookies value is now has a strip before each  value. Right now its something like 

-value1-value2

its supposed to be
 
valuea1-value2.

I have updated code above. Thanks